# Searching Points Mongodb $near

Tags: mongodb

```
 db.getCollection('places').find({
    "features.geometry":{
  $near: {
     $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates:[
    -834502.889188578,3970333.88258796
                        ]}
     ,
     $maxDistance: a given number
  }
}
});
```

Thats the code and what i want is to return documents whose geometry is near to
the  [`-834502.889188578,3970333.88258796`]
And tha(s the error

```
Error: error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ -834502.889188578, 3970333.88258796 ] }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: -834503 lat: 3.97033e+006",
    "code" : 2
}
```

Comment: You need to add what you've tried and what errors you've seen. Otherwise, you won't get helpful responses here.

Comment: Here it is And thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

These are not the valid lat and long values. Latitude range from +/- 90and longitude range from +/- 180.

These are not the valid lat and long values. Latitude range from +/- 90 and longitude range from +/- 180. And in mongo $geoNear coordinates first value is longitude and second value is latitude. pass as:

```
db.getCollection('places').find({
    "features.geometry":{
  $near: {
     $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates:[
    longitude, latitude
                        ]}
     ,
     $maxDistance: a given number
  }
}
});
```